# Concat, Groupby and sum() panda

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have some timestamped OHLC data that I am trying to recreate an uncompressed high-Low dataframe by iterating through the original OHLC dataframe.

OHLC dateframe looks like this:

```
                       open    high     low   close  index1    r1 TPO
timestamp                                                            
2014-05-07 09:30:00  187.40  187.62  187.16  187.16       0  0.46  NA
2014-05-07 10:00:00  186.96  187.32  186.13  186.18       1  1.19  NA
2014-05-07 10:30:00  186.47  186.90  186.47  186.88       2  0.43  NA
2014-05-07 11:00:00  186.78  186.97  186.67  186.68       3  0.30  NA
2014-05-07 11:30:00  186.85  187.69  186.85  187.69       4  0.84  NA
```

The idea here is to recreate each bar in the row and create a dataframe of the filled range.  for each row I call a function to recreate the filled range for the row i.  this works fine and creates and returns the row dataframe in x1 or x2.

Next, I want to append, Concatenate the dataframe to the the one prior in a cumulative concat function..It also appears to do this correctly

```
def TPOprint(low,high,tick):
  range=np.arange(low,high,tick)
  p1=pd.DataFrame({'Price':range,'Count':np.ones(len(range),dtype=np.int)},index=range)
  return p1

for i, row in bars.iterrows():
    if counter>0:
        low=bars.low[i]
        high=bars.high[i]
        x2=TPOprint(low,high,tick_size)
        if x2.empty:
            print('DataFrame is empty! Skipped ', bars.index1[i])
        TPOtemp=pd.concat([x1,x2])
        x1=TPOtemp

TPO=x1.groupby(x1.index)      
g=TPO.sum()
```

Lastly, after all the concatenations are completed, I want to group by price and get the sum of count at each price... this is where the problem really occurs.  Even though I perform the group by, duplicate prices are not combining and therefore summing is not happening. You can see the output below is not correct. I am stuck and don't understand why.

I ultimately want to perform histograms on this data, so if anyone know why this is happening I would appreciate it.

```
        Count  Price
186.46      1  186.46
186.47      1  186.47
186.47      1  186.47
186.48      1  186.48
186.48      1  186.48
186.49      1  186.49
186.49      1  186.49
186.50      1  186.50
186.50      1  186.50
186.51      1  186.51
186.51      1  186.51
186.52      1  186.52
186.52      1  186.52
186.53      1  186.53
186.53      1  186.53
186.54      1  186.54
186.54      1  186.54
186.55      1  186.55
186.55      1  186.55
186.56      1  186.56
186.56      1  186.56
186.56      1  186.56
186.57      1  186.57
186.57      1  186.57
```

Comment: What's the tick_size?

Comment: Your `tick_size` variable seems to be undefined. Also, `np.arange(low,high,tick)` would mean the price is evenly distributed between the lowest and highest price, which I think is hardly true.

Comment: tick_size is .01..price is evenly distributed based on sampling rate and does not effect the calculation. This is no different than the range traveled on "n" Minute OHLC candletick.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, maybe your values have more decimals not displayed?    Maybe try `df[['open','high','low','close']] = np.round(df[['open','high','low','close']], 2)`